# Encrypt data using Objective-C and Decrypt in Python

Tags: python, objective-c, encryption, aes

I have the same issue as [this question](http://www.itanswerz.com/1665939/issue-with-aes-encryptdecrypt-objective-c-python-tornado) but unfortunately there was no answer on it.

I have the following objective-c code to encrypt using `CCCrypt`:

```
(NSData *)doCrypt:(NSData *)data usingKey:(NSData *)key withInitialVector:(NSData *)iv mode:(int)mode error: (NSError *)error
{
    int buffersize = 0;
    if(data.length % 16 == 0) { buffersize = data.length + 16; }
    else { buffersize = (data.length / 16 + 1) * 16 + 16; }

    // int buffersize = (data.length <= 16) ? 16 : data.length;
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    void *buffer = malloc(buffersize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(mode, 0x0, 0x1, [key bytes], [key length], [iv bytes], [data bytes], [data length], buffer, buffersize, &numBytesEncrypted);

    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted freeWhenDone:YES];
}
```

I use `kCCAlgorithmAES128` with `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` as options and call the function with `[Cryptor doCrypt:data usingKey:key withInitialVector:nil mode:0x0 error:nil];`

Now I would like to decrypt it using python and to do so I have the following code:

```
def decrypt(self, data, key):
        iv = '\x00' * 16

        encoder = PKCS7Encoder()
        padded_text = encoder.encode(data)

        mode = AES.MODE_CBC
        cipher = AES.new(key, mode, iv)
        decoded = cipher.decrypt(padded_text)
        return decoded
```

The PKCS7Encoder looks like this:

```
class PKCS7Encoder():
    """
    Technique for padding a string as defined in RFC 2315, section 10.3,
    note #2
    """
    class InvalidBlockSizeError(Exception):
        """Raised for invalid block sizes"""
        pass

    def __init__(self, block_size=16):
        if block_size < 2 or block_size > 255:
            raise PKCS7Encoder.InvalidBlockSizeError('The block size must be ' \
                    'between 2 and 255, inclusive')
        self.block_size = block_size

    def encode(self, text):
        text_length = len(text)
        amount_to_pad = self.block_size - (text_length % self.block_size)
        if amount_to_pad == 0:
            amount_to_pad = self.block_size
        pad = chr(amount_to_pad)
        return text + pad * amount_to_pad

    def decode(self, text):
        pad = ord(text[-1])
        return text[:-pad]
```

Yet whenever I call the `decrypt()` function, it returns garbage. Am I missing something or having a wrong option enabled somewhere?

---

Example in and output:

```
NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithRandomData:16];
    NSLog(@"key: %@", [keyData hex]);
    NSString *str = @"abcdefghijklmno";
    NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
    NSData *encrypted = [Cryptor encrypt:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] usingKey:keyData];
    NSLog(@"encrypted str: %@", [encrypted hex]);
```

Gives:

```
key: 08b6cb24aaec7d0229312195e43ed829
str: a
encrypted str: 52d61265d22a05efee2c8c0c6cd49e9a
```

And python:

```
cryptor = Cryptor()
encrypted_hex_string = "52d61265d22a05efee2c8c0c6cd49e9a"
hex_key = "08b6cb24aaec7d0229312195e43ed829"
print cryptor.decrypt(encrypted_hex_string.decode("hex"), hex_key.decode("hex"))
```

Result:

```
láz
```

Which is weird, but if dump the hex I get `610f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fb02b09fd58cccf04f042e2c90d6ce17a` and `61 = a` so I think it just shows wrong.

A bigger input:

```
key: 08b6cb24aaec7d0229312195e43ed829
str: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
encrypted str: 783fce3eca7ebe60d58b01da3d90105a93bf2d659cfcffc1c2b7f7be7cc0af4016b310551965526ac211f4d6168e3cc5
```

Result:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaôNÍ“ƒ˜�Üšw6C%
```

Here you see that the a's are printed with garbage... so I assume this is a padding error or something like that

The IV is nill at the iOs side and 16x 0's at the Python side (see the code)

Comment: Provide test data in, key, iv and data out for both in hex dumps. Note CCCrypt expects data in and data out. It is better to not use hex values for the mode and options: `kCCAlgorithmAES128`, `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` & `kCCBlockSizeAES128`.

Comment: To add to the comment by @ArtjomB there must always be padding. Even if the data size is a whole multiple of the block size, a block of padding must be added. This is because the decrypting method must have a padding size. See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). But that will only affect the last block.

Comment: I added example in and output, I will try the mentioned change by @ArtjomB.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you nailed it. It was indeed first the decrypt and then the unpadding that was required. Could you make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The output `610f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f` makes sense,there is one character, the block size is 16 bytes so there are 15 bytes of padding, the 15 `0f` bytes.

Comment: Also, thank you @zaph for suggesting to use the modes instead of hex and helping me debug :)

Comment: @zaph No I didn't, apparently this is implemented following a RFC and I remember from class that if the data is a multiple of the block size, a whole block with padding has to be added... so it does make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your decryption:** `aes_decrypt(pkcs7_pad(ciphertext))`
**Correct decryption:** `pkcs7_unpad(aes_decrypt(ciphertext))`

It has to be done this way, because AES in CBC mode expects plaintexts of a multiple of the block size, but you generally want to encrypt arbitrary plaintexts. Therefore, you need to apply the padding before encryption and remove the padding after decryption.

---

Keep in mind that `a - (b % a)` cannot be 0 for any (positive) value of `a` or `b`. This means that

```
if amount_to_pad == 0:
    amount_to_pad = self.block_size
```

is unreachable code and can be removed. Good thing is that `a - (b % a)` already does what you wanted to do with the `if` block.

You also should extend the unpad (`decode`) function to actually check whether every padding byte is the same byte. You should also check that the every padding byte is not zero or larger than the block size.